# Codeigniter show controller if session exists

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I'm new to codeigniter and learn it.

I got 2 controllers, 1st one called main and responds for user registration / login the second one is called todo and shows a todo list.

Now if I access localhost/list my website opens the page, where do I write the session logic to test if user is logged in?

My controller todo

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Lists extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('lists');}
}
```

How do I display it using the session:

```
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == 1)
```

Or do I have to put the session logic before each function?

Comment: `public function __construct()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') != 1) { //redirect }
    }`

Comment: Hey @RazibAlMamun thank you, but where do I insert it in my code?

Comment: i have submitted my answer.

Comment: Please stop begging people not to down-vote you at the start of your question.  Not only is this kind of extraneous noise discouraged from postings, it's *more likely* to get down-voted.  For further information, please read:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the session `$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')` condition in `__construct()`

Like this :

```
<?php
class Lists extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') != 1) { 
            //redirect code here
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('lists');}
    }
}
```